# Google Sheets - Add Value if another cell has specific word

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to do the following in Google Sheets:

```
_____________
| YES | 100 |
| NO  | 100 |
| YES | 100 |
=============
| SUM | 200 |
```

So basically, the SUM is all values added that have the keyword YES in another cell.

Is that possible with a regular formulae? Or do I need some sort of script?

Answer (score 3):

SUMIF(range, criterion, [sum_range])

You need to use the third (optional) argument because the range to be summed is different than the range.

```
=SUMIF(A1:A3,"=YES",B1:B3)
```